# Handling Failed Connection on Proxy for Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I have the following line of code which I use to scrape the html for a site. As you can see I pass in a proxy into this

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(Scrape.scrape_url + page.to_s, :proxy => 'http://177.19.134.66:8080'))
```

Some times these proxys go down and I then get the error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond  after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host  has failed to respond. - connect(2)

I am very new to ruby but what I would like to do is create a list of Proxy IP addresses. and then get it to attempt to scrape using the first. and if its fails then try the next one until there is none left to check...

How would I go about creating a list and then handling the error?

Answer (score 3):

simplest would be:

```
['http://localhost:8080','http://localhost:8888','http://localhost:8000'].each do |proxy|
  break if @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(Scrape.scrape_url + page.to_s, :proxy => proxy)) rescue nil
end
```

Notice '@doc' because 'doc' will go out of scope when the loop ends.